# How to get the open rate of the notification sent from the Firebase notifications console?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-analytics, firebase-notifications

I configured and installed the sample Firebase quick start app for android https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/messaging and ios https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/tree/master/messaging.

I was able to send notifications from the Firebase console but when I open the notification, I can't see the open rate in the Firebase console backend.

According to the documentation, the open event is automatically fired, when a user clicks on the notification.

Are there any more steps involved to see the open rate of the notifications sent from the console?

Also is there a way to send a notification from the API and still get the open rate for those notifications?

Comment: This will take up to 48-72 hours to update on console.. So you can see the open rate on analytics after 48 hours.. However you can also see realtime by applying the adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE,
adb shell setprop log.tag.FA-SVC VERBOSE,
adb logcat -v time -s FA FA-SVC commands.

Comment: Sounds like an answer Arpit!:-)

Answer (score 2):

If you have implemented **UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate** on iOS 10, you need to call

> Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)  // it sends confirming message to Firebase Cloud Messging

in these two delegate methods

```
public func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
    Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
}

public func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
    Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
    completionHandler()
}
```

otherwise, you need to implement this UIApplicationDelegate method:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
   [[FIRMessaging messaging] appDidReceiveMessage:userInfo];
   completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include firebase analytics related dependancy in gradle. Open rate is part of analytics library.

Check if you have included both of these :
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.4.0'

Comment: Same situation happens to me. I have compiled both libraries specified by you. The problem is that when I tested the first time I was able to see target rate and open rate. But after a few weeks when I sent the second push notification and no data is displayed for target and open rate.